# autocad zoom object to center screen

Tags: zooming

i cannot seem to reason out why the code below does not zoom to center of the selected objects. usually the objects are near the center but at the top of the screen.

i can use `doc.SendStringToExecute("ZOOM " + "OBJECT " + objIdString + " ", true, false, false);` and i can get exactly what i want, but not when i want it because the call is from a button on a modeless dialog and is then the last event to occurr.

my objective is to step through and zoom center object selectons pausing with a yes/no to continue dialog between each.

any help will be appreciated.

```
public static void ZoomObjects(ObjectIdCollection idCol)
{
    Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
    Database db = doc.Database;
    Editor ed = doc.Editor;
    using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    using (ViewTableRecord view = ed.GetCurrentView())
    {
        Matrix3d WCS2DCS = Matrix3d.PlaneToWorld(view.ViewDirection);
        WCS2DCS = Matrix3d.Displacement(view.Target - Point3d.Origin) * WCS2DCS;
        WCS2DCS = Matrix3d.Rotation(-view.ViewTwist, view.ViewDirection, view.Target) * WCS2DCS;
        WCS2DCS = WCS2DCS.Inverse();
        Entity ent = (Entity)tr.GetObject(idCol[0], OpenMode.ForRead);
        Entity ent1 = (Entity)tr.GetObject(idCol[0], OpenMode.ForWrite);
        Extents3d ext = ent.GeometricExtents;
        for (int i = 1; i < Enerflex.SpoolTagFindForm1.idColCnt; i++)
        {
            ent = (Entity)tr.GetObject(idCol[i], OpenMode.ForRead);
            ent1 = (Entity)tr.GetObject(idCol[i], OpenMode.ForWrite);
            Extents3d tmp = ent.GeometricExtents;
            ext.AddExtents(tmp);
            ent1.Color = Color.FromColor(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
        }
        ext.TransformBy(WCS2DCS);
        view.Width = ext.MaxPoint.X - ext.MinPoint.X;
        view.Height = ext.MaxPoint.Y - ext.MinPoint.Y;
        view.CenterPoint = new Point2d((ext.MaxPoint.X + ext.MinPoint.X) / 2.0, (ext.MaxPoint.Y + ext.MinPoint.Y) / 2.0);
        ed.SetCurrentView(view);
        tr.Commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer to the discrepancy with the zoom objects extents. when selected, some objects containing MaxPointX & Y and MinPointX & Y that are identical (text objects) adversely affected the zoom view. when i did not select these objects the zoom worked as expected.